# Pytorch CUDA out of Memory if GPU is not “warmed up”?

Tags: python, pytorch, nvidia

I have a simple script as follows:

```
import torch
LOSS_WEIGHTS = [1,2,3]
LOSS_WEIGHTS = torch.Tensor(LOSS_WEIGHTS)
LOSS_WEIGHTS = LOSS_WEIGHTS.to(0)
```

If I start the script while the computer is idle, I often get “CUDA error: out of memory” yet the GPU is completely empty.

The error somehow always goes away after I repeatedly relaunch the script several times. Does anyone know what can I do to prevent this error? Am I suppose to initialise my cuda device before starting the script?

- pytorch 1.2.0 (Tried several versions)
- cuda 10.1 (Also tried cuda 9)
- python 3.7
- Nvidia Driver 430
- Hardware: 1 x GTX 1070
- Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: it sounds like there is an initialization with cuda and your script is trying to run a process before that is fully initialized. Maybe use `with` to check for availablity? https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html

Comment: Thanks! Adding `with torch.cuda.device(0):`  with a block of indented code seems to work get rid of the error completely. This seems to complicate the code a bit since i want the code to sometimes run with CPU on another PC for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing like this (assuming you have only 1 GPU)

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

Also you can check gpu if it is available and online using a command like

```
nvidia-smi
```

Comment: Adding the line to my example shows that `device` is cuda but the problem of CUDA error: out of memory still persists before the GPU fan starts to spin.